# Propagate primary key changes but not cascade deletes on FireDAC centralized cached updates

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

FireDAC can cascade primary key changes and deletes when running in [centralized cached updates](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Caching_Updates_(FireDAC)) mode, activating the [DetailCascade](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.DetailCascade) property.

But, is there a way to only cascade primary key changes while not cascading the deletes ?.

Thank you.